# How to check condition for key and value in python dictionary for specific value

Tags: python

how to check whether my key has value of `<class 'inspect._empty'>`

Dictionary looks like :

```
{'abc': <class 'inspect._empty'>, 'xyz': None}
```

Now, I want to set abc equal to x value if it has value `<class 'inspect._empty'>`

```
    def _arg_unset(args_dict: Dict, key: str) -> bool:
    """return True if key is not set to some actual value in args_dict"""
    return args_dict.get(key) in {None, Parameter.empty}
```

In above cod, dict needs to be passed as first param and key as second param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> d = {'abc': inspect._empty, 'xyz': None}
>>> d
{'abc': <class 'inspect._empty'>, 'xyz': None}
>>> {k:v if v != inspect._empty else 'x' for k,v in d.items()}
{'abc': 'x', 'xyz': None}
>>>
```

Comment: kindly see my question and found an optimized way to check this as well None value for specific key in dict.